# ANTLR semantic evaluation

Tags: antlr

I want to support a Haskell-like list construction from another previously defined list
 ex: [ 2*x+1 | x<-list1] ; and at the same time do the evaluation and print the new list.

i have tried the following:

```
constructlist
    :   {   ArrayList<Integer> myList= new ArrayList<Integer>();    
            ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();}

        '[' op1= expression '|' op2= expression '<' '-' IDENT ']'

          { myList= lists.get($IDENT.text);                                         
            for(int i=0;i<myList.size();i++)
            {
                variables.put($IDENT.text,myList.get(i));
                newList.add($op1.result);
            }

            {System.out.println(newList);}                                  


    ;
```

But this definitely won't work. I have expression returning the result of any expression (ex: x*y + 2... provided the variables are previously initialized.

can anyone suggest a way of doing this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found Partial answer. This is called forward referencing in ANTLR.
http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/CS652/Forward+references+solution 
But my problem is that expression is the only thing that can return the result, so i can't just store expression in a list and then check for the syntatic structure. i need to do the evaluation in parallel